# Ubuntu on VirtualBox is not booting

Tags: boot, virtualbox

I have searched EVERYWHERE but my ubuntu STILL won't boot on VBox.

It doesnt give me any error, it just stalls. I downloaded the ISO officialy from the [ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/download) website but it still isn't working.

Any idea why?

It also flashes text on screen in the VBox window before it stalls but I can't read it fast enough.

I have tried recording it and tried to view it but it's too fast and I cant find the exact spot.

Can someone help? Thanks.

EDIT: I am on version 20.10

Comment: What is the host machine (hardware and OS)? What is "the linux website"?

Comment: Sorry I meant ubuntu. It's this website: ubuntu.com/download 
Uhh I don't know about the hardware but I know i'm on Windows 10. Hold on I will try to get details about my hardware (and I guess motherboard?)

Proccesor is: AMD A6-9500 RADEON R5 - Thats all I could find.

Comment: Did you verify the checksum (ie. ISO is perfect?)  https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0   or you can just compare sha256sum with web site..

Comment: Try to create a new virtual machine with the recommended settings for 64 bit Ubuntu..

Comment: Thanks guiverc and FedonKadifeli, I have fixed it. I just had to, like FedonKadifeli said, make a new VM with the recommended settings :)

Comment: Also I did verify it, it was fine.

Comment: try to change Display/Graphics controller to VMSVGA or VBoxVGA